# How to get sample rate of mp3 file using python

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, sample-rate

I need to play this mp3 file using pygame but I dont know what the sample rate of the file is. I need some way to programaticaly get the sample rate of the audio file so that I can play it at the correct rate cuz  if I dont then it just distorts the sound. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown):

```
>>> from pydub import AudioSegment
>>> song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("file.mp3")
>>> song.frame_rate
44100
```

Or use `pydub.utils.mediainfo()`:

```
>>> from pydub.utils import mediainfo
>>> info = mediainfo("file.mp3")
>>> print(info['sample_rate'])
44100
```

Comment: sorry I should have said this in the original post but I have tried that already but I cant seem to install the ffmpeg dependancy for that :/

Comment: try to install the wheel version

Comment: You can also install the deps. [readme](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#getting-ffmpeg-set-up)

Comment: Installing the wheel version worked for me thank you so much!

Comment: This isn't a very efficient method. AudioSegment parses the entire MP3 file, which isn't necessary if all you want to get is meta data, like frame rate.

Answer (score 2):

The pydub answer is pretty good, until you use it with pyinstaller. Here is how to do what you are looking for with mutagen.

```
# Specifically MP3 file
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
audio_info = MP3('FILENAME.mp3').info

# Generic audio file
import mutagen
audio_info = mutagen.File('FILENAME.ext').info

print(audio_info.sample_rate)
```